# jupyter notebook: running cell does not work

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

[Hanging Jupyter Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWcmV.jpg)

I am trying to run this cell but it does not work. It shows **( In [*] )** unlike other cells. I tried to go to kernel and interrupt & restart and try other solutions but still does not fix anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO :).  Fixed up your question a little.  Try to name your pictures well, and you can avoid general pleasantries to keep it lean (e.g. no need to say please help or thank you and all that).  Hope you have fun here and learn a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

That message means the cell is actively running already.  It's "evaluating".

So, either:

- Wait a while and it will finish.
- Or you may have bad logic that creates an infinite loop, or waits forever, etc.
- Also look for things that may block/timeout over a long period (certain web calls, db connections, whatever).

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tutorial/

> This cell doesn’t produce any output, but it does take three seconds to execute. Notice how Jupyter signifies when the cell is currently running by changing its label to In [*].